How to skip certain fields in JSON object when parsing to improve performance?
I am receiving a large stringified JSON object, with several fields, some of which are big. For example, let's say the object is something like:
{
  "somethingHuge": (200 000 character string)
  "relevantField": true
}

I am only interested in relevantField, so to save performance, I don't want to parse somethingHuge, allocate memory to hold that string, etc. Is it possible to skip that field when parsing?
Note: the object's shape is decided by external factors, there's no way to receive just the relevant data.

You could potentially hack the string up to remove those large/long values before you parse the JSON. However, you will still have to load the entire string in to memory to do that (and also download the entire thing assuming it's being retrieved from a remote source). As with all issues like this, it's a case of garbage in, garbage out. The best solution is to avoid this from ever happening by not storing the values you don't need for this specific functionality.

@RoryMcCrossan Indeed, in my case I can't avoid transferring the data over a network, and also loading the big stringified JSON into memory. But I had hoped to at least not double-load the same unnecesasry data into memory by also making the huge parsed object.

You could use the reviver argument to avoid the field being stored on your result object. It will still be parsed, but at least it can be thrown away immediately and your resulting object won't need to allocate space for the property.


const json = "{ \"somethingHuge\": \"(200 000 character string)\", \"relevantField\": true }";

const parsedObject = JSON.parse(json, (key, value) => {
  return key === "somethingHuge" ? undefined : value;
});

console.log(parsedObject);



Not sure how much of a performance benefit this would be since I haven't measured it but without doing something like removing it form the JSON string parsing (or using a custom JSON library) I don't see any other way around it.

Thanks! Indeed seems like the only way with the native JSON parsing API. Will try to run some performance metrics and see if it helps.
